# Automation of graphs by Canvas tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

Can we automate graphs generated using canvas tag for test automation in selenium using python?I want to extract the data points plotted on the graph.

Comment: Selenium alone cannot see inside the `CANVAS` tag. You will need to either get the devs to add an API for you or if the graph is generated by an existing library, see if they have a published API.

Answer (score 0):

You can using ocular ,if your graph is not dynamically changing for every second.

Through selenium we cannot automate graphs.

You can refer to http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-automate-charts-and-graphs-validation/

you can embed ocular along with selenium code

Comment: Thanks. But the graph changes every day.Does it support python?

Comment: it is a java utility.

Comment: Something for python? 
I also want to extract the marked points.